# Dialog themed activity with action bar

Tags: android

In a v3 android application, is it possible for an activity that has a dialog theme (e.g.: Theme.Holo.Dialog) to have an action bar? I tried adjusting the windowIsFloating Attribute, but that caused an exception along the lines of "actionbarimpl not compatible", indicating that the current dialog theme does not support action bars?

It should be possible as several applications on the Samsung Galaxy Tab have dialogs with action bars.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425020/actionbar-in-a-dialogfragment/12275009#12275009

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but I just wanted to express my immeasurable gratitude in advance. This one was very frustrating for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dialog Theme wasn't designed to display an ActionBar. 
[Read this for more information.](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/dialogs.html)

When using a Dialog you want the user to choose between different options and make some decisions. I don't know what your Use-Case is but you better change your UI-Design so that you can manage your use-case with another solution. A solution Android was designed for.

> If you really want to use a Dialog with a ActionBar, you can create your own by using a
>   [Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog) with a custom layout and build a ActionBar clone-layout.

Comment: You're right. Dialogs don't have those, but it was quite jarring to find a lot of the Samsung apps have dialogs with "action bars" only to find out later that it's not something you get as standard while actually developing an application.