# Display Activity as overlay window on tablets

Tags: android, android-activity, tablet

How do you present an Activity as an overlay window on tablets? An example of this is the new Google+ app as seen here:

[image]

Importantly I want the ActionBar to be part of the window and for the Activity beneath to be dimmed as seen in the screenshot.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use dialog theme. To do this, just write in Manifest:

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

or

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog"
```

or just by creating your own theme in styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Holo.Dialog">
...
</style>
```

You can set such theme for xlarge or large screen by creating styles.xml in values-xlarge or values-large folders.

If you want to set this theme only for tablets, then you can change theme dynamically by checking the screen size like this:

```
if (Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE)
{
//setTheme(yourDialogTheme);
}
```

Please check this answer if you want dialog with action bar. You can do this by creating your custom dialog.

[Dialog themed activity with action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630162/dialog-themed-activity-with-action-bar)

[Custom dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

EDIT:
An answer from [google group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/Y5wnstMT5Lo). Try this
in your xml with styles:

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateAlwaysHidden</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
```

In Java code

```
public static void showAsPopup(Activity activity) {
        //To show activity as dialog and dim the background, you need to declare android:theme="@style/PopupTheme" on for the chosen activity on the manifest
        activity.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
        LayoutParams params = activity.getWindow().getAttributes(); 
        params.height = LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT;
        params.width = 850; //fixed width
        params.alpha = 1.0f;
        params.dimAmount = 0.5f;
        activity.getWindow().setAttributes((android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams) params); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `Theme.Dialog` in you `Manifest.xml` for the Activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

for future use you should use an CustomTheme in you values/values-11/values-14->`styles.xml` (EDIT)

EDIT:

```
         <activity 
             android:name="com.apps.ActivityP" 
             android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"/>
```

in you values `styles.xml` folder

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
```

for example you values-11/14 `styles.xml` folder

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
```

Comment: I have tried this and it has no effect on my Nexus 10.

My Manifest:
<activity android:name="com.apps.ActivityP" android:theme="@style/MyFloatingWindow" />

Styles.xml
<style name="MyFloatingWindow" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>

Comment: Also you should check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: Thanks, android:Theme.Holo.Dialog did the trick. Not sure why, perhaps I was overriding other styles somewhere else.

However, I dont seem to be able to use the ActionBar using that Theme. I get a nullpointer calling: actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: I edited my previous comment, I just realised I cannot use ActionBar when using the android:Theme.Holo.Dialog theme, any ideas?

Comment: Check my answer please, about the action bar.

Comment: Please try this solution and add the parameters to your layout [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425020/actionbar-in-a-dialogfragment)

Comment: Still the issue with null pointer being thrown when accessing the ActionBar. I may have to look into yyunikov suggestion of a custom Dialog?

Answer (score 1):

You need to extent your activity theme with

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge
```

or

```
Theme.Holo.DialogWhenLarge
```

Here is an example

```
<style name="AppTheme.DialogActivity" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DialogWhenLarge">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!-- Your theme here -->
</style>
```